# opencv non-active application, window Error when i tried "imshow()"

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, user-interface, imshow

[my xcode error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aIqX.png)

[CODE]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    cout << "openCV Version: " << CV_VERSION << endl;
    
    Mat image = imread("img.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    namedWindow("Original Image");
    imshow("Original Image", image);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[ERROR]
2023-10-29 17:39:35.782532+0900 surename[4309:273575] [Window] Warning: Window CVWindow 0x108d1c010 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows.
2023-10-29 17:39:35.783451+0900 surename[4309:273862] [client] No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid
Program ended with exit code: 0

I use **opencv** in these environment: M1 Mac(ver.13.4(22F66)), Xcode(Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)), C++

And i install and build opencv in this routine.

- **git clone** opencv & opencv_extra_modules
- **brew** install cmake
- **cmake** & make & sudo make install

And i set xcode like this.

- **header search path**: ".../opencv/install/include/**"
- **library search path**: ".../opencv/install/lib"
- **other linker flags**: output from **"pkg-config —cflags —libs opencv4"** in terminal.
  (install folder have cmake install things cause i have cmake option. CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.../opencv/install)

I think there are some problems related to **dynamic library link**... But i cannot sure about this exactly.

I tried xcode setting(**RunPath Search Paths**: "…/install/lib" & Signing&Capabilities-Rumtime Exception-**Disable Library Validation CHECK**).
And add Environmanet Variable and PKG_CONFIG_PATH to my **.zshrc** file.

Answer (score -1):

From search, i recovered this error doesn't matter to me. I just want to make cv code and check that result in xcode.
So, in my case the only one to do is add those 2 code.
This shows my result Window correctly.

```
namedWindow("Original Image");
imshow("Original Image", image);
waitKey(0); //add this
destroyAllWindows(); //add this
```